# Media Query Issue on landscape orientation

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am developing a responsive website and I'm applying the below media CSS queries:

**Query1:**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /*My Styling*/}
```

**Query2:**

```
@Media screen and (max-width:768px) { /*My Styling*/ }
```

**Query3:**

```
@Media screen and (max-width:1024px) { /*My Styling*/ }
```

I am also doing this meta statement in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

For some reason the second and the third query are being applied fine but when I test the first query (Practically targeting iPhone landscape) none of the defined styles get applied.

Comment: Try making the "M" in media caps like your second and third query

Comment: Are you sure the styles aren't applying but are getting overwritten by your second and third media queries?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly no as when I set my browser to that width, and inspect the element they are showing in the list of rendered css.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified a min-width for other queries you should organize your css like this:

query3

query2

query1

That way your last level of css will be applied correctly without getting overwritten by your other queries.

Emulation of a iphone device in landscape orentation in chrome works as intended:
http://www.bootply.com/tumubw4Ztq

```
@Media screen and (max-width:1024px) { body{background-color:red;}}
@Media screen and (max-width:768px) { body{background-color:yellow;}}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { body{
 background-color:blue;}}
```

[image: Emulation results]

Comment: When I implemented your above suggestion, for some reason when I change the order of the queries they are not getting applied :S... however, when I place in the this order Query1, Query2, Query3 - Query 2 & 3 worked but not the 1...What can be the reason?

Comment: @user3690480 You are surely overwriting your styles that way, could you paste in your complete css on a fiddle (or codepen or botply or whatever) with some kind of demo so i can debug?

Comment: @user3690480 gona need the DOM elements or else I can't preview the result, there also seems to be missing 1 query and the css isn't well formed